# Returning an Updated Row in Integration Test C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

In my code I originally have a test method that disable a row by calling a stored procedure. My stored procedure updates the `disable` column if the value changed from the previous value in the database, otherwise I do a regular update, the regular update exclude the update of the disable column.

```
IF(@ThingID IS NOT NULL)    
BEGIN      
    SELECT @StoredDisable = Disable FROM Things WHERE ThingID = @ThingID        
    --If the Disable value is different then we are doing   
    IF(@Disable != @StoredDisable)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE Things 
                SET Disable=@Disable
                WHERE ThingID = @ThingID            
            SET @ResultMessage = 'Successfully Deleted'
            SELECT @ResultMessage AS 'Message'                
            RETURN 0
            END     
        END       
    ELSE --If the Disable value is the same then we are just updating the fields  
    BEGIN
            UPDATE Things               
            SET thing1=ISNULL(@thing1, thing1),thing2=ISNULL(@thing1, thing2).....  
                WHERE thingID = @thing1ID                                                                   
            SET @ResultMessage = 'Successfully Updated'
            SELECT @ResultMessage AS 'Message'                                          
            RETURN 0                
    END     
END
```

I have tested this in my SQL Server manager and it works perfectly fine. But when I run it in my test it does not disable the row but instead updates the rows. The first time I was doing it on a pre-existing row in my DB, but later on I inserted my own row before I try to disable it

```
command.Parameters["@ThingID"].Value = DBNull.Value;
command.Parameters["@Comment"].Value = "Inserted from test";

command.ExecuteNonQuery();

 using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
 {
--Insert a new row and got the ordinal and the value of Disable (store in atemp)
--and the thingId (store in result.Id)
Console.WriteLine("the row Disable: {0}",     
    atemp);                                   
 }
  -----------Insert Done----------

 Console.WriteLine("the row id: {0}", result.Id);

 command.Parameters["@ThingID"].Value = result.Id;
 //command.Parameters["@Comment"].Value = "Disable from test";
 command.Parameters["@Disable"].Value = 1;

 connection.Open();
 command.ExecuteNonQuery();

  using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
  {
var tempDisable = false;
var DisableOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("Disable");
while (reader.Read())
{
    tempDisable = reader.GetBoolean(DisableOrdinal);
}
Console.WriteLine("the Disable before: {0}", tempDisable);
reader.NextResult();

reader.NextResult();
while (reader.Read())
{
    tempDisable = reader.GetBoolean(DisableOrdinal);
}
Console.WriteLine("the Disable After: {0}", tempDisable);   
 }                      
 ... the rest of code
```

What I did was added a select statement to my insert so that I can get the result set adn see the value of `Disable` which is false as expected. I then added one select statement in my disable/update stored procedure before doing anything to get a result set to see what disable is, and it is true and I have not done anything yet and as a result it is calling the update section which does not update the disable column. So I do not know what is going on. Below is the output console form my test

```
the row Disable : False
the row id: 1898
the Disable before: True
the Disable After: True
```

Comment: You mean integration or system test, right? Testing a database is NOT a unit test.... mock it out

Comment: Opps Lol I was doing a unit test before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must have been called twice:
1) You disabled it
2) Because @Disable parameter == 1 it is same as the existing value so you update the values

Why it was called twice it is the other question - maybe something stupid - like test executed twice or some debugger Watch that executes the command to get the value watched (sounds funny but that is what happened once to me ;)

Comment: I stepped through the debugger and everything got executed once like expected.

Comment: Hey your right, I just notice that my `@@indentity` which I use or my IDs are being incremented by 2 now to find out why. **Suggestion?**

Comment: So apparently the store procedure is already executed somewhere, and when I call `ExecuteNonQuery` is execute the store again. Wierd.

Comment: So apparently when  I added this bit of code `using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))` at the beginning it automatically executed my SP and then alter on when I did the `ExecuteNonQuery` it executed a 2nd time.